# Define a custom Event/Error to emit with WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I am using WebdriverIO to write automation tests for my application. I came across this page: http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/eventhandling.html and was wondering if I can possibly define a custom error or event to emit with NodeJS.

I know that I can use NodeJS and the EventEmitter Module to customize a error event, but how can I integrate that with WebdriverIO and the "wdio" test runner?